# Jenkins AAPT is not picking up my android:background attribute in the styles

Tags: android, jenkins

I have the following issue

When I build my project locally my styles are in tact. However, when I run a Jenkins job that is configured to run a task like:

`clean lint uT assembleDeviceDebug produceSecurityScanSource performFortifyScan -Ptheme=release --refresh-dependencies`

I noticed that my android:background was ignored so I inlined the attribute like so:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/selector_toggle_button"
    android:background="@null"
    style="?attr/attr_selector_toggle_button_appshop_settings_rowitem" 
/>
```

Both Jenkins and my local are using the same SDK so no difference there. Only thing is Jenkins is running on Linux and I am running on windows.